# Which Rally API is used for creating defect now?

Tags: rally

I tried all sample and getting error - It is no longer necessary to append ".js" to WSAPI resources. Please Help with example.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That is just a warning- it's not actually preventing anything from working.  Can you give us some more info on how you're accessing the api?  Are you writing an app?  Are you using one of the REST toolkits?  Are there other errors in your response?

That warning just means you can drop the .js from all of the ref urls.  The proper defect creation endpoint in wsapi version 2 is this:

`/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/create`

Comment: I am using this link - https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide
As suggest, I have added all dependency and calling below method in my Java project.

RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "_fad8f7HD348");
 restApi.setApplicationName("CrudExample");
JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
 newDefect.addProperty("Name", "Test Defect");
 CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", newDefect);
 CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

Comment: While accessing createResponse object, I am getting below error:-
{"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["Could not read: Object not found for Object ID: null"], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."]}}

Comment: Can you share postman URL to create defect with request and header used, if possible.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I'd try specifying a specific project in your request to make sure it's creating it where you expect.  Also, is it possible there are any required fields of type object?  Iteration?  Requirement?  Something in there is expecting to have an object relationship specified that you're not specifying.  I agree that there could probably be a more descriptive error message....

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyle, I tried to debug the issue in postman and found  request was expecting "Priority" value as mandatory input. using below request I am able to proceed, same I added in java code and that also works fine. 
Request use :
{
"Defect":{
"Name": "bad defect",
"Priority":"Normal"
}
}